# How to add a custom class to Semantic UI?

Tags: css, less, semantic-ui

**Where** and **how** do I add a custom class like:

```
 .my-custom-class {
  color: red;
 }
```

*The reason is so it won't change all of the Semantic UI elements too.*
In which file do I add it for it to be included in the dist file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to change the Semantic-UI elements, why don't you just have a completely separate CSS file for custom styling?

It's completely fine (and quite common) to have multiple CSS files, such as with the following structure:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="ui" href="/dist/semantic.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
```

Then in `custom.css`, simply include your additional custom styling:

```
.my-custom-class {
  color: red;
}
```

The order in which the external stylesheets are loaded directly corresponds to the [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/); loading your custom stylesheet **after** Semantic-UI will give it more specificity in the case of a tie.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I'd like it to bundle into the semantic.min.css file too, and have less capabilities (with gulp watch) is that possible too in an elegant way?

Comment: You can watch for changes to multiple files in Gulp with something like `watch('css/**/*.css', function () { } )`, and pipe them to a single file as output. However, I wouldn't recommend changing Semantic-UI's CSS at all; its essentially a plugin. In keeping them separate, you'll be able to isolate your custom CSS from Semantic-UI's inbuilt CSS, and spot a potential problem far more easily. It also allows for far easier 'style modification' by simply swapping out the order of the CSS files in the HTML.

Comment: Hi thanks, there is the problem of specificity here. SUI will always win in your solution. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: It depends on the class names used both both SUI and your custom CSS (you can use completely different class names if need be), though the stylesheet that is loaded last is always granted one bonus point of specificity. If you have identical selectors, the stylesheet loaded last will win. And you can always provide more specificity than SUI. For example, `.ui.checkbox input.hidden+label` will be beaten by `body .ui.checkbox input.hidden+label`. I don't believe SUI uses `!important`, but an `!important` declaration with more specificity will still overwrite any `!important` statements in SUI :)